# JQuery UI menu prevent submenu item collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to prevent submenu item of Jquery UI not collapse when I click on it, now it is default collapsed, here is example when click on submenu item, it will collapse.

http://jsfiddle.net/cR4EK/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = $('#menu');
    menu.menu();

    var blurTimer;
    var blurTimeAbandoned = 200;  // time in ms for when menu is consider no longer in focus

    menu.on('menufocus', function() {
        clearTimeout(blurTimer);
    });

    menu.on('menublur', function(event) {
        blurTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            menu.menu("collapseAll", null, true );
        }, blurTimeAbandoned);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:

```
$("#menu").menu({
    select: function(e, ui) {
        $("#menu").menu("focus", e, ui.item);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VPXjs/1/
so just ignore it.